# How to link static library to QT creator project properly?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

I have created a very simple static library in Visual Studio 2013 and i want to use it in a QT Creator project.

MyLib.h:

```
void printSomething();
```

MyLib.cpp

```
#include "MathLib.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void printSomething(){
    cout << "VS lib: printSomething" << endl;
}
```

I build this lib with Visual Studio 2013 using the following settings:

- Platform Toolset: Visual Studio 2013 (v120)
- Configuration Type: Static Library
- Code Generation: Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd)

I link this Static Library with a qt project with the following qmake directives:

- LIBS += -L".lib path" -lMyLib
- INCLUDEPATH += "header file path"

I build qt projects with Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler 12.0 64-bit.

So... When i build the qt project i get "unresolved external symbol" for the lib functions i use in the project. Qmake finds the lib and include paths fine.

**Important Note:** When i create the same static library as a project in qt creator, it works fine.

**Edit**:

Here is the .pro file of qt creator project

```
QT += core gui 
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets 
TARGET = TestingQt 
TEMPLATE = app 
SOURCES += main.cpp\ mainwindow.cpp 
HEADERS += mainwindow.h 
FORMS += mainwindow.ui 
RESOURCES += \ testingresources.qrc 
LIBS += -L"path" -lMathLib 
INCLUDEPATH += "path"
```

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: please post the full .pro file; did you set `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += /MTd`?

Comment: No i haven't. I have edited the first post including the .pro file.

Comment: does setting this flag help resolve the unresolved symbols?

Comment: I have used Debug:QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += /MTd in .pro file.
This time i get: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MTd_StaticDebug' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in main.obj

Comment: Done for both lib build and qt project build.
Debug:QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += /MTd for .pro file and 
/MTd for Runtime library in vs project properties.

Comment: Update: when i build the lib from VS using /MDd it works fine with qt Project. The problem is that i can modify qt project to use /MTd.